Need help defining constraints regarding start and end time on job shop scheduling AGV

// Decision Variables

dvar boolean X[T][M][R]; // Binary variable indicating if task i of mission m is performed by resource r

dvar boolean Y[M][R]; // Binary variable indicating if resource r is assigned to mission m

dvar boolean Z[R]; // Binary variable indicating if resource r is occupied and assigned to a mission

dvar float+ St[T][M] in 0..1000; // Start time of task i of mission m

dvar float+ C[T][M] in 0..1000; // End time of task i of mission m

dvar float+ W[M][R][T]; // Energy consumed to perform task i of mission m on resource r

I need help to reformulate the start and end time of each task in each mission because my approach didn't work and gave me illogical results (negative values)

Welcome to OR.SE. You would need to edit your question and focus on the part you actually want to know about rather than just Ctrl+C/V the model and code.
